# how to check null for anchor href property in Adobe CQ5 Components.?

Tags: jsp, adobe, aem, jcr

Hi all i'm getting values from JCR in CRXDe these are rendering fine, but i have an a little issue, i want if url field is null that time it doesn't show any destination HREF but i'm not getting success my code is as:

```
    <a href="<%= obj.get("url") %>"><%= obj.get("label") %></a>
```

and for another field i'm doing like this, which is working perfectly:

```
 <c:if test="${not empty properties.videoImage}">
    <img src="${properties.videoImage}" />
</c:if>
```

here i want to check  "<%= obj.get("url") %>"  is null so how can i do this, can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried the same solution something like this `<a href="${not empty properties.videoImage?properties.videoImage:''}">${not empty properties.label?properties.label:''}></a>` [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482451/ternary-operator-in-jstl-el) for more details.