# Modify class of a button tag in a JSP on the basis of EL value

Tags: jsp, el

My button tag in the JSP is

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger student-age">
<span class="age">${student.age}</span>
</button>
```

I want my button class btn-danger to be changed to btn-success if student age is greater than 18.

student.age is coming from java code using EL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a ternary expression:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn ${student.age gt 18 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'} student-age">
<span class="age">${student.age}</span>
</button>
```

Or if you need greater than or equals to, use `ge` instead of `gt`.

See also:

- [Ternary operator in JSTL/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482451/ternary-operator-in-jstl-el)

Comment: that's awesome, had no idea it was possible to use in the class like that

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL `lt` and `gt` (less than and greater than)

```
<c:if test="${student.age gt 18 || student.age eq 18}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success student-age"><span class="age">${student.age</span></button>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${student.age lt 18}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger student-age"><span class="age">${student.age</span></button>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I used ternary expressions instead  :)

Comment: This will fail if age equals 18

Comment: ah yeah good point. Edited. Your solution is way simpler anyway.